# PHP: as API+Views or just API

Tags: php, laravel, templates, cakephp, templating-engine

Note: This is an opinionated question. I m asking this as I was unable to find proper articles covering my concern.

PHP (alone or with a framework like laravel) can be used for both backend and frontend (with templating engines like Blade,Smarty,etc) development.

My concern is:

1. Is it good to use templating engine and create views in PHP?
2. Use PHP just as a backend tech and create APIs, let the frontend be built in any other language (like Angular,React,etc) chosen by the front end developer.
3. If I use templating-engine, is my application getting too tightly coupled between frontend tech choices and backend tech choices?

PS: I hope my concern is clear, if not I will explain it in an elaborated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion: If You are building small-medium size web project, don't bother to use frontend frameworks, because You just don't so much horses in such small environment. But when it comes to larger project with scaling - it is recommended to use some kind of frontend framework, because eventually that kind of project will be (or it should be) maintained by a team, so backenders can focus on backend - frontenders on frontend.

A lot of folks says that web developer is a web developer, there is no backend or frontend. But in my opinion, they are just not faced that kind of project where You need separate things.

You can be good at everything or You can be master and specific niche, choose Your path wisely.

Comment: So for a project which is going to get extended over time, its better to separate out the API layer and the views layer?

Comment: @SandipanMitra If project gets bigger and bigger, at the some point You will feel that Your frontend is a mess, same as backend, so better start project by separating things from the start to avoid that mess. But You have to think twice about that, because some projects does not require so much of frontend functionality, so it makes no sense to use frontend framework. So in short: it depends when to separate or when to keep it together.

Comment: Kirsys Thanks a lot mate. Gives me a clearer view now.

Answer (score 0):

1. IMHO it's a waste of resources. CakePHP doesn't use a template engine by default. The only valid reason to add a template language is when you want templates from external people you can't trust and parse them first without running them directly in php. The argument that designers shouldn't have to learn php or Ruby is silly. People who claim this obviously never looked at Smarty or any other template language. If they re-implement operators like "if / else" in their template engine it doesn't matter if they have to learn the underlying language or the template "language". And honestly, it's 2016, I simply would pick a designer who has a basic understanding of my programming language. There are skilled people if you search a little and pay them good money.
2. It's a matter of proper architecture and design decisions if this makes sense or not. Technically possible - yes.
3. Same answer as two plus the developer skills.